# Подскажите как сделать чтобы иконка кнопки увеличивалась в размерах вместе с кнопкой?

Tags: python, pyqt5, resize, qicon

У меня есть кнопка которая увеличивается по горизонтали и вертикали и есть иконка в этой кнопки, я хочу чтобы она также меняла размер как и кнопка, возможно ли это сделать.

Вот иконка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Image')
        but = QPushButton(self)
        but.setIcon(QIcon('13.png'))
        but.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        bbb = QVBoxLayout()
        bbb.addWidget(but)
        self.setLayout(bbb)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо сделать свою кнопку через наследование и переопределить событие `resizeEvent`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QResizeEvent

class MyPushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyPushButton, self).__init__(parent)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.setIconSize(event.size())
        super().resizeEvent(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    button = MyPushButton()
    button.setIcon(QIcon(<Путь к иконке>))
    button.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```